# Connections icon not visible in status bar

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10

I think there are two distinct issues I have:

1) **Cannot see the wifi icon in top bar**. I can connect with wired networks and also see the list of wireless networks as shown in screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Networks menu]

2) **Cannot connect to wireless networks**. On trying to connect to wifi from Networks settings, nothing happens.

One of the things that I tried is `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` as suggested on an another question for 16.04.

Operating System: 16.10

PS: This is not a fresh install. I was doing some experiments on ARP poisoning. Wifi was working back then.

Comment: There is no screenshot in your question

Comment: @zakoda screenshot added

Comment: Did you happen to remove the _network-manager-gnome_ package?

Comment: Related: http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/06/howto-force-remote-devices-routersswitches-to-refresh-their-arp-cache-entry-for-a-machine/

Comment: @dobey I tried `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`

Comment: @MeetTaraviya But is the _network-manager-gnome_ package installed or not?

Comment: @dobey How do I find out?

Comment: Well, it must be installed now, given that you accepted the answer below which suggested that you install some stuff you don't need, as it installed what you need and solved the problem. But `apt-cache policy network-manager-gnome` would show you if it's installed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
$ sudo apt install indicator-applet-complete
```

Comment: What then? Just installing something can't fix anything

Comment: The process of installing something configures the default for the install.  You will have the defaults of the Network Manager indicator for the status bar set after this install.  I had the icon disappear in more than one computer.  This resolved the issue each time for me.  You might have logout and log back or reboot in to see the updated effect.

Comment: No. This package has nothing to do with the default indicators, and is not even seeded in Ubuntu. It is for the applet for the old gnome panel, like the one in MATE. It has nothing to do with indicators in Unity.

Comment: You're welcome... it's a pleasure giving back to the community!